# Pyglet, why triangle edges is not showed in wireframe mode?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I'm just a beginner in graphics development.

Now i'm trying to extend cocos2d python (pyglet) functionality.

My target is make class of rectangle object for making platform game.

All is okay. But when toggling in wireframe mode - i cant see edges of my rectangle, i need it.

Can anyone describe how to support wire-frame mode with my solution?

Code example:

```
class ExtRect(cocos.cocosnode.CocosNode):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super(ExtRect, self).__init__()
        self.rect = cocos.rect.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    def draw(self):

        gl.glPushMatrix()

        self.transform()

        gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1)

        #...draw...

        pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(4, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
            [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
            ('v2i', (
                self.rect.x, self.rect.y,
                self.rect.x + self.rect.width, self.rect.y,
                self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.rect.height,
                self.rect.x + self.rect.width, self.rect.y + self.rect.height
            ))
        )

        gl.glPopMatrix()
```

Without filling color it works as need:

[image]

But when i applied color with glColor4f, edge disspears:

[image]

I also tried to adding colors values to indexed vertex-list data ('c3B', (0, 0, 255, 0) * 4) - result is the same.

Comment: I need logical explaination on open gl level. Don't need to jump in pyglet releasation and it details.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of [Primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) in OGL:

- Point primitives: `GL_POINTS`
- Line primitives: `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_LINE_LOOP`
- Triangle primitives: `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`

Point primitives draw single points, line primitives draw lines. Triangle primitives either draw, points, lines or filled polygons according to the settings of [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml)

This means, if you want to draw a wire-frame, then you have to set the polygon mode as follows:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

Comment: "triangle primitives draw filled triangles" That is not true. They draw points, lines or filled triangles, depending on the setting of [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml).